# Тест - ответить на неотвеченные

Tags: php, javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы после прохождения теста была возможность по нажатию кнопки ответить на те вопросы, которые отвечены неправильно?
Сам тест:

```
ФИО, Курс обучения(обязательно)<span class="need">*</span>:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" class="text" size="40" maxlength="100"><br>
Email <span class="need">*</span>:<br>
<input type="text" name="email" class="text" size="40" maxlength="100"><br>
<a id="test_go">Начать тестирование</a>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#test_go').click(function(){
        $('.questions').show();
    });
    function lastElem(str){
        if(str){
        return str.substring(str.length-1,str.length);
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    $('#test_end').click(function(){        
        $.post(
          "/sendmail.php",
          {
            name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
            email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
            q1:lastElem($('input[name=q1]:checked').attr('id')),
            q2:lastElem($('input[name=q2]:checked').attr('id')),
            q3:lastElem($('input[name=q3]:checked').attr('id')),

          }
          );
         $.post(
          "/test/index.php",
          {
            name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
            email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
            q1:lastElem($('input[name=q1]:checked').attr('id')),
            q2:lastElem($('input[name=q2]:checked').attr('id')),
            q3:lastElem($('input[name=q3]:checked').attr('id')),

          }, onAjaxSuccess
          );

            function onAjaxSuccess(data)
                {
                alert(data);
            }

        });
});

</script>
<div class="questions">
   <ul>
        <li>
            <span>1 Вопрос:</span><br />
            <input type="radio" name="q1"  id="v1_1"  /><label for="v1_1">Ответ 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q1"  id="v1_2"  /><label for="v1_2">Ответ 2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q1"  id="v1_3"  /><label for="v1_3">Ответ 3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q1"  id="v1_4"  /><label for="v1_4">Ответ 4</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>2 Вопрос:</span><br />
            <input type="radio" name="q2"  id="v2_1"  /><label for="v2_1">Ответ 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q2"  id="v2_2"  /><label for="v2_2">Ответ 2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q2"  id="v2_3"  /><label for="v2_3">Ответ 3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q2"  id="v2_4"  /><label for="v2_4">Ответ 4</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>3 Вопрос</span><br />
            <input type="radio" name="q3"  id="v3_1"  /><label for="v3_1">Ответ 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q3"  id="v3_2"  /><label for="v3_2">Ответ 2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q3"  id="v3_3"  /><label for="v3_3">Ответ 3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q3"  id="v3_4"  /><label for="v3_4">Ответ 4</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a id="test_end">Закончить тестирование</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в /test/index.php идет обработка данных. В случае успеха происходит выполнение функции onAjaxSuccess. Соответственно сделаете функцию onError, в которой будете говорить о том, что что-то неудачно, конкретно: ответы на такие-то вопросы были некорректны

В /test/index.php соответственно обработка if (все ответы верны) echo 'success'; 
И уже только по success отправлять письмо на email ;)

if (не все верны) echo 'error' + массив с номерами вопросов, где был дан неправильный ответ.

И что за костыльная функция lastElem? Раз уж используете jquery, то берите значение инпута

```
$('input[name=q1]:checked').val();
```

сам сам инпут

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" id="v1_1" /><label for="v1_1">Ответ 1</label>
```